# How to install on top of other windows phpstorm IDE?

Tags: ide, phpstorm

How to install the editor on top of other windows? 
OS: windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in facilities in PhpStorm or Windows to do it. You'll need some 3rd party utility, which can set "aways on top" flag for PS window.

Quick googling gives AutoIt script http://www.labnol.org/software/tutorials/keep-window-always-on-top/5213/ and some utilities i.e. http://www.fadsoft.net/AlwaysOnTopMaker.htm to accomplish this.